# How to duplicate a child descriptor onto STDOUT_FILENO and STDERR_FILENO

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the GNU `popen` library but having issues with `dup2`. I want to duplicate the child pipe to both `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO`.
 I am little confuse here with the dup2, because it says on the man page that dup2 closes the old descriptor, how how can use duplicate pipe onto `STDERR_FILENO` after doing this `dup2(pipe_list[child_fd], child_fd)`. Because from what i do understand upon a call to dup2 the `oldfp` will be closed and this `dup2(pipe_list[child_fd], STDERR_FILENO)` will not work because `pipe_list[child_fd]` was already closed. Should i use `dup` and after that close `fd` or there is a way to achieve this with `dup2`?

```
#define tpsr(a,b) (*type == 'r' ? (b) : (a))
#define tpsw(a,b) (*type == 'w' ? (b) : (a))


static FILE *fp_stream = NULL;
static pid_t popen_pid = -1;
static const char * const shell_path = "/bin/sh";


FILE *mypopen(const char *command, const char *type) {

    int pipe_list[2];
    int parent_fd, child_fd;


    if (type == NULL || type[1] != 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (type[0] != 'w' && type[0] != 'r') {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }


    if (pipe(pipe_list) == -1) {
        return NULL;  //errno will be set
    }

    child_fd = tpsr(STDIN_FILENO,STDOUT_FILENO);
    parent_fd = tpsw(STDIN_FILENO,STDOUT_FILENO);
    /*The above (tpsr and tpsw) are the same as this
        if type[0] == 'r'
        child_fd = STDOUT_FILENO; //1 child will be doing the writing
        parent_fd = STDIN_FILENO; //0 parent read

       if type[0] == 'w'
        child_fd = STDIN_FILENO; //0 child doing the reading
        parent_fd = STDOUT_FILENO;//1 parent do the writing
    }*/


    if ((popen_pid = fork()) == -1) {
        close(pipe_list[0]);
        close(pipe_list[1]);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (popen_pid == 0) {
        // we got a child here

        if (pipe_list[child_fd] != child_fd) {

            if (dup2(pipe_list[child_fd], child_fd) == -1) {
                (void) close(pipe_list[child_fd]);
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
              //is this the right way after the oldfd is closed by dup2
            if (child_fd == STDOUT_FILENO) {
                if (dup2(pipe_list[child_fd], STDERR_FILENO) == -1){
                    (void) close(pipe_list[child_fd]);
                    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

            }

            (void) close(pipe_list[child_fd]);
        }
        (void) pipe_list[parent_fd];


        (void) execl(shell_path, "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit(127) required by man page

    } else {

        (void) close(pipe_list[child_fd]);
        if ((fp_stream = fdopen(pipe_list[parent_fd], type)) == NULL) {
            (void) close(pipe_list[parent_fd]);
            return NULL;
        }


    }

    return fp_stream;
}
```

Comment: Reread the [`man 2 dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) man page. It says that when you call `dup(oldfd, newfd)`, and `newfd` was previously open, it (`newfd`) will be closed. It does not close `oldfd`. So, if `dup2()` succeeds, both `oldfd` and `newfd` will be open, and refer to the same open thingy.

Comment: Thanks but most of the information here is confusing, like [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html#l22)  before the last page example, it   `NOTES: the old descriptor is closed with dup2()!`

Comment: @NominalAnimal so linking the child to both` STDOUT_FILENO and STDERR_FILENO` will not cause any problem, and i will be able to get the output and errors

Comment: Let's say you have created a pipe in `pipefd[2]`. Then, `pipefd[0]` is the read end, and `pipefd[1]` is the write end. If you want all output from the child to be directed to the pipe, then the child process usually does `close(pipefd[0]); dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); dup2(pipefd[1], STDERR_FILENO); if (pipefd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO && pipefd[1] != STDERR_FILENO) close(pipefd[1]);`. The second `dup2()` can be written equivalently as `dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO)` without any difference in behaviour. The parent does just `close(pipefd[1])`, and reads child output from `pipefd[0]`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal yea i understand your logic. So my second dup2 is ok right because i have two option which is read and write. for read I redirect all output from child to pipe, dup to stdout and stderr but with write, the child process doesn't have to redirect or pipe to stderr. so that is why in my second if clause i was doing this `if(child_fd == STDOUT_FILENO)` before dup2 to stderr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`dup2(fd1, fd2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html):

- If `fd1` is not an open file descriptor, the function will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EBADF`. `fd2` is not closed.
- If `fd2` is outside the allowed range, or if it is not open but the process already has the maximum number of open file descriptors (`RLIMIT_NOFILE`), the function will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EBADF`.
- If any other problem occurs, the function will return `-1` with `errno` set to some error code. It is not specified whether `fd2` is untouched or closed in this case.

  The rest of the cases below assume the operation is successful.
- If `fd1 == fd2`, the function will return `fd1` (which is the same as `d2`).
- If `fd2` is not an open descriptor, then `fd1` is duplicated to it. The two descriptors then refer to the same *file description* (the stuff like file position that the kernel keeps).
- If `fd2` is an open file descriptor, it gets closed when `fd1` is duplicated to it. The closing is *silent*, meaning that any error due to the closing is silently ignored.

The main point is, that only `fd2` may be closed, and only if `fd2 != fd1` and if `fd2` was previously open. In no case is `fd1` closed.

---

I cannot really follow your logic with regards to your code. In particular, using the `parent_fd` and `client_fd` as indexes to `pipe_list[]` seems suspect to me. Furthermore, the function should return both a file handle, as well as the child process PID.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct {
    FILE *child_pipe;
    pid_t child_pid;
    int   exit_status;
} cmd;

/* open() analog, except moves the descriptor to the
   number specified. You cannot use O_CREAT flag.
   Returns 0 if success, -1 if an error occurred,
   with reason in errno. */
static int open_fd(const int fd, const char *path, const int flags)
{
    int tempfd;

    if (fd == -1 || !path || !*path || (flags & O_CREAT)) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    tempfd = open(path, flags);
    if (tempfd == -1)
        return -1;

    if (tempfd != fd) {
        if (dup2(tempfd, fd) == -1) {
            const int failure = errno;
            close(tempfd);
            errno = failure;
            return -1;
        }
        if (close(tempfd)) {
            const int failure = errno;
            close(fd);
            errno = failure;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/* pipe[] analog, except ensures neither endpoint
   matches STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO, or STDERR_FILENO.
*/
static int create_pipe(int fd[2])
{
    /* I like to initialize return parameters.. */
    fd[0] = -1;
    fd[1] = -1;

    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
        return -1;
    else {
        const int  close_stdin  = (fd[0] == STDIN_FILENO) || (fd[1] == STDIN_FILENO);
        const int  close_stdout = (fd[0] == STDOUT_FILENO) || (fd[1] == STDOUT_FILENO);
        const int  close_stderr = (fd[0] == STDERR_FILENO) || (fd[1] == STDERR_FILENO);
        int        failure = 0;

        do {

            while (fd[0] == STDIN_FILENO ||
                   fd[0] == STDOUT_FILENO ||
                   fd[0] == STDERR_FILENO) {
                fd[0] = dup(fd[0]);
                if (fd[0] == -1) {
                    failure = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (failure)
                break;

            while (fd[1] == STDIN_FILENO ||
                   fd[1] == STDOUT_FILENO ||
                   fd[1] == STDERR_FILENO) {
                fd[1] = dup(fd[1]);
                if (fd[1] == -1) {
                    failure = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (failure)
                break;

            if (close_stdin)
                close(STDIN_FILENO);
            if (close_stdout)
                close(STDOUT_FILENO);
            if (close_stderr)
                close(STDERR_FILENO);

            return 0;
        } while (0);

        /* Whoops, failed: cleanup time. */
        failure = errno;

        if (fd[0] != STDIN_FILENO &&
            fd[0] != STDOUT_FILENO &&
            fd[0] != STDERR_FILENO)
            close(fd[0]);
        if (fd[1] != STDIN_FILENO &&
            fd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO &&
            fd[1] != STDERR_FILENO)
            close(fd[1]);
        if (close_stdin)
            close(STDIN_FILENO);
        if (close_stdout)
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        if (close_stderr)
            close(STDERR_FILENO);

        errno = failure;
        return -1;
    }
}
#define  CMD_PASS     0
#define  CMD_READ     1
#define  CMD_DISCARD  2

int cmd_read(cmd        *pipe,
             const char *path,
             char       *args[],
             const int   stdout_mode,
             const int   stderr_mode)
{
    int   pipefd[2], controlfd[2], cause;
    FILE *handle;
    pid_t child, p;

    /* If pipe is not NULL, initialize it. */
    if (pipe) {
        pipe->child_pipe = NULL;
        pipe->child_pid = 0;
        pipe->exit_status = 0;
    }

    /* Verify the parameters make sense. */
    if (!path || !args || !pipe ||
        stdout_mode < 0 || stdout_mode > 2 ||
        stderr_mode < 0 || stderr_mode > 2) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Do we need the pipe? */
    if (stdout_mode == CMD_READ || stderr_mode == CMD_READ) {
        if (create_pipe(pipefd) == -1)
            return -1;
    } else {
        pipefd[0] = -1;
        pipefd[1] = -1;
    }

    /* We use a control pipe to detect exec errors. */
    if (create_pipe(controlfd) == -1) {
        cause = errno;
        if (pipefd[0] != -1)
            close(pipefd[0]);
        if (pipefd[1] != -1)
            close(pipefd[1]);
        errno = cause;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Parent reads from the control pipe,
       and the child writes to it, but only
       if exec fails. We mark the write end
       close-on-exec, so the parent notices
       if the exec is successful. */
    fcntl(controlfd[1], F_SETFD, O_CLOEXEC);

    /* Fork the child process. */
    child = fork();
    if (child == (pid_t)-1) {
        cause = errno;
        close(controlfd[0]);
        close(controlfd[1]);
        if (pipefd[0] != -1)
            close(pipefd[0]);
        if (pipefd[1] != -1)
            close(pipefd[1]);
        errno = cause;
        return -1;
    }

    if (!child) {
        /* This is the child process. */
        close(controlfd[0]);
        if (pipefd[0] != -1)
            close(pipefd[0]);

        cause = 0;
        do {
            if (stdout_mode == CMD_READ) {
                if (dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
                    cause = -1;
                    break;
                }
            } else
            if (stdout_mode == CMD_DISCARD) {
                if (open_fd(STDOUT_FILENO, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY) == -1) {
                    cause = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (cause)
                break;

            if (stderr_mode == CMD_READ) {
                if (dup2(pipefd[1], STDERR_FILENO) == -1) {
                    cause = -1;
                    break;
                }
            } else
            if (stderr_mode == CMD_DISCARD) {
                if (open_fd(STDERR_FILENO, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY) == -1) {
                    cause = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (cause)
                break;

            if (pipefd[1] != -1)
                close(pipefd[1]);

            if (path[0] == '/')
                execv(path, (char *const *)args);
            else
                execvp(path, (char *const *)args);

            /* Failed. */
        } while (0);

        /* Tell parent, why. */
        cause = errno;
        /* To silence the warn_unused_result warning: */
        if (write(controlfd[1], &cause, sizeof cause))
            ;
        close(controlfd[1]);

        exit(127);
    }

    /* Parent process. */
    close(controlfd[1]);
    if (pipefd[1] != -1)
        close(pipefd[1]);

    do {
        ssize_t  n;

        /* Read from the pipe to see if exec failed. */
        n = read(controlfd[0], &cause, sizeof cause);
        if (n == (ssize_t)sizeof cause)
            break;
        if (n != 0) {
            cause = EIO;
            kill(child, SIGKILL);
            break;
        }
        close(controlfd[0]);

        if (pipefd[0] != -1) {
            handle = fdopen(pipefd[0], "r");
            if (!handle) {
                cause = errno;
                kill(child, SIGKILL);
                break;
            }
        } else
            handle = NULL;

        /* Success! */
        pipe->child_pipe = handle;
        pipe->child_pid = child;

        return 0;
    } while (0);

    /* Failed; reason is in cause. */
    if (pipefd[0] != -1)
        close(pipefd[0]);

    /* Reap child. */
    while (1) {
        p = waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
        if ((p == child) || (p == (pid_t)-1 && errno != EINTR))
            break;
    }

    errno = cause;
    return -1;
}

int cmd_wait(cmd *pipe)
{
    pid_t  p;

    if (!pipe || pipe->child_pid == -1)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    while (1) {
        p = waitpid(pipe->child_pid, &(pipe->exit_status), 0);
        if (p == pipe->child_pid) {
            if (pipe->child_pipe)
                fclose(pipe->child_pipe);
            pipe->child_pipe = NULL;
            pipe->child_pid  = 0;
            return 0;

        } else
        if (p != -1) {
            if (pipe->child_pipe)
                fclose(pipe->child_pipe);
            pipe->child_pipe = NULL;
            pipe->child_pid  = 0;
            errno = EIO;
            return -1;

        } else
        if (errno != EINTR) {
            const int cause = errno;
            if (pipe->child_pipe)
                fclose(pipe->child_pipe);
            pipe->child_pipe = NULL;
            pipe->child_pid  = 0;
            errno = cause;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    off_t   total = 0;
    char   *line  = NULL;
    size_t  size  = 0;
    ssize_t len;
    int     stdout_mode, stderr_mode;
    cmd     run;

    if (argc < 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Usage:\n");
        printf("       %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("       %s MODE COMMAND [ ARGS ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Where MODE may contain:\n");
        printf("       o  to retain output,\n");
        printf("       O  to discard/hide output,\n");
        printf("       e  to retain errors, and\n");
        printf("       E  to discard/hide errors.\n");
        printf("All other characters are ignored.\n");
        printf("If there is no 'o' or 'O' in MODE, then output\n");
        printf("is passed through to standard output; similarly,\n");
        printf("if there is no 'e' or 'E' in MODE, then errors\n");
        printf("are passed through to standard error.\n");
        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (strchr(argv[1], 'o'))
        stdout_mode = CMD_READ;
    else
    if (strchr(argv[1], 'O'))
        stdout_mode = CMD_DISCARD;
    else
        stdout_mode = CMD_PASS;

    if (strchr(argv[1], 'e'))
        stderr_mode = CMD_READ;
    else
    if (strchr(argv[1], 'E'))
        stderr_mode = CMD_DISCARD;
    else
        stderr_mode = CMD_PASS;

    if (cmd_read(&run, argv[2], argv + 2, stdout_mode, stderr_mode) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (run.child_pipe) {
        while (1) {
            len = getline(&line, &size, run.child_pipe);
            if (len == -1)
                break;

            total += (off_t)len;

#ifdef PRINT_PIPE_CONTENTS
            if (len > 0)
                fwrite(line, (size_t)len, 1, stdout);
#endif
        }
        if (ferror(run.child_pipe) || !feof(run.child_pipe)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error reading from pipe.\n", argv[2]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (cmd_wait(&run) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Lost child process: %s.\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Read %llu bytes from child process.\n", (unsigned long long)total);

    if (WIFEXITED(run.exit_status))
        fprintf(stderr, "Child exited with status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(run.exit_status));
    else
    if (WIFSIGNALED(run.exit_status))
        fprintf(stderr, "Child terminated due to signal %d.\n", WTERMSIG(run.exit_status));
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Child lost.\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you save the above as **pipe_example.c**, you can compile it using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 pipe_example.c -o pipe_ex
```

and test it by running e.g.

```
./pipe_ex  oe  sh -c 'printf "OUT\n"; printf "ERR\n" >&2; exit 5'
./pipe_ex  Oe  sh -c 'printf "OUT\n"; printf "ERR\n" >&2;'
./pipe_ex  -E  sh -c 'printf "OUT\n"; printf "ERR\n" >&2; kill -TERM $$'
```

The above code is, as you can obviously see, quite complicated -- and overall, it is just a `popen()` analog, but with fewer features.

However, it does everything quite carefully (except perhaps passing the reason the exec failed from the child to the parent -- there I am simply *assuming* the write succeeds). As such, it might be useful as an example of how many details (and at least one way of dealing with such details) there are in practical multiprocess programs. And, of course, how useful standard POSIX.1 [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) is.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and a supporting code. Yea very complicated but helpful

Comment: with regards to `parent_fd` and `client_fd` as indexes to  `pipe_list[]`, i did so because of the options/ mode read or write for the popen type parameter. i used `tpsr and tpsw ` to set the `parent_fd and the child_fd` before the fork, so if the passed parameter option for type is `r` then parent_fd = 0 which is read and child_fd = 1 which is write. which is the same as `pipe_list[option here]` in dup2 is `dup2(pipe_list[child_fd], child_fd)` same as `dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO)`. I just decided to use this simple logic to minimise code duplicate.

Comment: @SeekAddo: I see. Fact is, it makes understanding the code a lot harder. Sometimes code duplication is okay -- for example, when it makes it much easier to understand. In your case, if you want to keep that concise code, I'd suggest a comment block near the assignments to describe the logic. (I suggest this, because it is likely that in a few months or a year, you yourself might forget what you thought when you wrote that. I definitely do, when I use tricks like that.)

Answer (score 0):

A bit more detailed example with stdout and stderr at the same time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int fdout[2];     /* pipe fd array for the stdout */
  int fderr[2];     /* pipe fd array for the stderr */
  pid_t pid;        /* process id */
  char buf[4096];   /* stdout and stderr buffer */
  int status;       /* place to store child process status */

  if (pipe(fdout)==-1)  /* first pipe for the stdout */
    perror("pipe out");    /* exit with error if something wrong */

  if (pipe(fderr)==-1)  /* second pipe for the stderr */
    perror("pipe err");    
    /*
    *   On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the
    *   parent, and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is
    *   returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is
    *   set to indicate the error.
    */
  if ((pid = fork()) == -1) /* fork current process and store pid */
    perror("fork error");

  if(pid == 0) { /* if pid == 0 than this is a child process */

    dup2 (fdout[1], STDOUT_FILENO); /* send stdout to the pipe fdout */
    dup2 (fderr[1], STDERR_FILENO); /* send stderr to the pipe fderr */
    
    /* close both sides of the pipe in the child */
    close(fdout[0]);
    close(fdout[1]);

    /* close both sides of the pipe in the child */
    close(fderr[0]);
    close(fderr[1]);


    /* execvp is called in the child ps 
     * argv[1] is a ptr to the first arg
     * &argv[1] is a ptr to a ptr to the first arg
     */
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]); 
    
    /* this part is never reached if execvp success */
    return errno;

  } else { /* parent */    
    while(wait(&status) > 0){} /* wait for the child processes to finish */
    
    /* close write ends of the pipes */
    close(fdout[1]);
    close(fderr[1]);
    
    /* if child process finished with errorprint error 
     * and return error code from parent process
     */
    if (WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status)){
      printf("%s\n", strerror(WEXITSTATUS(status)));
      return WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }

    ssize_t size;
    size = read(fdout[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("OUT: \"%.*s\"\n", (int)size, buf);

    size = read(fderr[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("ERR: \"%.*s\"\n", (int)size, buf);

    /* close read ends of the pipes */
    close(fdout[0]);
    close(fderr[0]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

compile and test:

```
ruslan@localhost:~/exec$ gcc main.c -o a && ./a /bin/ls 
OUT: "a
main.c
"
ERR: ""
ruslan@localhost:~/exec$ gcc main.c -o a && ./a /bin/ls ---sdfadsfsdf
OUT: ""
ERR: "/bin/ls: unrecognized option '---sdfadsfsdf'
Try '/bin/ls --help' for more information.
"
ruslan@localhost:~/exec$
```